# Powershell Get Windows Store Apps

Tags: powershell

Is there a programmatic way to retrieve Installation Date for all Windows Store apps? I can see the Install Date in Windows 10 Settings, but using Powershell, Get-AppxPackage does not include this property. They are not listed in the typical Uninstall registry key with non-Store apps.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe something like `Get-AppxPackage | % { get-item $_.InstallLocation} | select CreationTime, LastWriteTime, BaseName`?

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to what @JoseZ gave you already, there are a few other options.

Store apps are isolated apps and will not appear in Add/Remove or the registry uninstall strings by design. Thus polling there is moot.

Using Windows Explorer, you can see modern apps this way. Paste this...

```
explorer.exe shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-B780-3893943456e1}
```

...in the Windows Explorer bar, then change the view to detail, and you'll see that there is very limited data/metadata shown.

Unless you change the ACL, you cannot even directly enter the folder where they are stored.

> [C:\Program Files\WindowsApps](https://www.techmesto.com/windows-store-apps-installed-save-data/)

It is there that you can see the date info, etc.

So, if you are running PS as admin, the just do this...

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\' | 
Select-Object -First 1

# Results
<#
    Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                             
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                             
d-----         18-Nov-19     18:33                03552DDA.Hotels.com_0.4.0.1133_neutral_split.scale-180_hp3f0wmdc4jwt
#>
```

So, if you don't want to change the ACL, could use the MS Sysinternals tool PSExec (either from cmd.exe, powershel.exe, ISE or VSCode) running that as a system, then you can list the location and get the date.

```
.\psexec.exe -i -s powershell.exe'

PS C:\> gci 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\'

# Results
<#
    Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        11/18/2019   6:33 PM                03552DDA.Hotels.com_0.4.0.1133_neutral_split.scale-180_hp3f0wmdc4jwt
...
#>
```

Comment: The `Applications` folder can also be referenced by _Name_ rather than GUID: `shell:AppsFolder`. No need to specify `explorer.exe` in the _Address_ bar or **Run** dialog, only **Command Prompt** or **PowerShell**.

Comment: True and I do this shell: thing for many of the default folders, and no, no need to do the explorer thing while in the Windows File Explorer, but it is needed when calling to this via a command or script since PowerShell has no idea what that is. Windows Explorer has to be opened (either using explorer or start) for either to work at all. [shell:AppsFolder] or [& 'shell:AppsFolder'] # shell:AppsFolder : The term 'shell:AppsFolder' is not recognized. cmd.exe/PowerShell; this works, [explorer or start shell:AppsFolder]. WinKey+Run, defaults to start, so no need to specify.

Comment: Glad you agree.